# Passing var on onload function

Tags: javascript, php

Hie all,
Here is my code part.page1.php

```
<?php
$ID="1,2,3,4,";
$ID1=json_encode($ID);
?>
<html>
<script src="page.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<body onload="<?php echo'add('.$ID1.')';?>">
</body>
</html>

//page.js code
function add(oi1)
{
alert(oi1);
}
```

It gives me syntax error near add(..
I want to pass "1,2,3,4,"; on add function.

Comment: try escaping like `<body onload="<?php echo'add(\'.$ID1.\')';?>">`

Comment: add function in page.js file?

Comment: hty but $ID1 not taken as php ..meance on alert it gived $ID1 ..pls change the syntax and tell me

Comment: yes!  add function on page.js page@AyyanarG

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<body onload="add('<?php echo $ID1?>')">
```

It's often better writing like this instead of your example.

Comment: SyntaxError: unterminated string literal
 

add('[

Comment: Try removing the single quotes I put in add() you might also change the double quotes to single quotes instead, hence JSON could return double quotes.

Comment: Like this I mean: `<body onload='add(<?php echo $ID1?>)'> `

Comment: yes it gives me error SyntaxError: syntax error add([

Comment: Try adding the `function add(....){}` in `<script>` tag before `<body>` in the HTML. Same error again?

Comment: Try this, I do not get any error as literal in your code, put why are you `json_encode` a string that will return the same?
`<?php echo "<body onload='add(".$ID1.")'>";?>`

Comment: Please tell mw wht I do for solution

Comment: hey may I asked you one question.?

Comment: Ask away! Then we'll see if I could answer.

Comment: I want to change on this line.....    <body onload="<?php if($_GET['id'])  echo 'dload('.$_GET['id1'].','.$_GET['id2'].','.$_GET['id3'].','.$_GET['id4'].','.$_GET['id5'].','.$_GET['id6'].','.$_GET['id7'].','.$_GET['id8'].','.$_GET['id9'].','.$_GET['id10'].','.$_GET['id11'].' );';?>">

Comment: IN THIS THE $_GET['id2'] IS THAT I was looking for

Comment: can we chat on gmail?

Comment: Send me a mail instead: in the footer on my page [here](http://appallan.se/english/)

Comment: ok sorry I send you the mail ID is newest pls take this mail ID pratiksha0035@gmail.com